# Dont need id attribute which sequelize created automatically

Tags: database, sequelize.js

```
let data = require('./../../config/db')
let connection = data.connection
let sequelize = data.sequelize
let sql = function(){
    let clubMembers = connection.define('club_members',{
            position:{
                type :sequelize.ENUM('President','Treasurer') ,
                allowNull : false
            }
        },
        {
            classMethods : {
                associate : function(models){
                    let clubMembers = models.club_members
                    let club = models.club
                    let student = models.student
                    club.hasMany(clubMembers,{
                        foreignKey : "club_id"
                    })
                    student.hasMany(clubMembers,{
                        foreignKey : "student_id"
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    );
    return clubMembers;
}
module.exports = sql;
```

I dont need `id` attribute in this table but sequelize automatically creates it . And combination of both the foreign keys should be treated as primary key i.e composite primary key . 
[image]

Comment: Do you want to create many-to-many relation between club and student?

Comment: yeah its many-to-many relation

Comment: `club_member` table represents many-to-many relation so that club can have many students and student can belong to many clubs. Is that right?

Comment: yes you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`belongsToMany`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/docs/associations/#belongs-to-many-associations) in the `associate` function

```js
associate: function(models){
    models.club.belongsToMany(models.student, { through: models.club_members, foreignKey: 'club_id' });
    models.student.belongsToMany(models.club, { through: models.club_members, foreignKey: 'student_id' });
}
```

This would create the `club_members` table with composite primary key consisting of `club_id` and `student_id`, without the default `id` column.

Comment: Thanks it worked    

Just update this to `models.club.belongsToMany(models.student,{
                        through:models.club_members, foreignKey: 'club_id'
                    });    

                    models.student.belongsToMany(models.club, {
                        through: models.club_members, foreignKey: 'student_id'
                    });`